# Orthogonal Matrices and similarity

Tags: linear-algebra

Two questions:

Is it necessary true that,

1. **Every** **two** Invertible matrices with the same dimension are similar to each other.
2. **Every two** row equivalence matrices with the same dimension are similar to each other.

If one of them is wrong, give an example. Otherwise, prove.

Well for the first one it is necessary true that every 2 orthogonal matrices with the same dimension are similar to each other because after doing elementary row operations on both of them we get the same Identity matrix (because the dimension is the same). And then we can say that if M is orthogonal then and A,B are those two matrices:

$M^{-1}AM = B \longrightarrow M^{-1}IM = I \longrightarrow I = I$ which is true.

For the second one, well I didn't give an example, but I'm pretty sure that if we take two matrices with the same dimension with the same row equivalence they won't necessary be similar to EVERY TWO matrices that we take because:

Assume $A \ne I_n$ and A is orthogonal matrix then: (also: $A$ is  row equivalent to $I_n$)

$A = M^{-1} I_nM \longrightarrow A = M^{-1}M \longrightarrow A= I_n$
So $A = I_n$ which can't be true because $A \ne I$ so A can be row equivalent but can't be similar.

By the way, if you guys can example me that better or give other examples/proves it will be much appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Counter example for both stataments: $I$ and $-I$.

Comment: 1. is not true even in the scalar case, that is, $+1$ is not similar to $-1$.

Comment: @GitGud Can you show me how you use I and -I to prove (1.) is wrong?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Clearly they are orthogonal. It should be known to you that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @GitGud Didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: When dealing with matrices, it is a good idea to see if the $1 \times 1$ case works. In the $1 \times 1$, no two distinct numbers are similar, since $q x q^{-1} = x$.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Well, it's an important part of the reasoning. If you don't know it, you should learn how to prove it.

Comment: @GitGud I just noticed I didn't study eigenvalues yet. Can you give another prove?

Comment: 2. is "almost never" true. For 1., two matrices in $SO(2)$ resp. $SO(3)$ are similar iff they rotate "clockwise" by the same angle. In $SO(4)$, I would guess that a similarity class is determined by 2 oriented angles in two orthogonal 2-planes.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Thank you for asking for this. What I said is true, but it is a big overkill. Here's a more elementary and more elegant proof: suppose $I$ and $-I$ are simular. Then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}IP=-I$. Can you conclude?

Comment: My bad: (1.) is for every two Invertible matrices (not ortho), I translated it wrong.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Work with scalars first. If its not true for scalars, it is not true for general matrices...